# First Ajax Request fails in Firefox with Nginx 1.10 and HTTP/2

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, nginx, http2

Since i upgraded from Nginx 1.8 to 1.10 and activated HTTP/2 instead of SPDY the first ajax call (over https) i trigger in Firefox fails.
If i execute the same call again it works. In Chrome and IE this Problem doesn't occur. Deactivating HTTP/2 solves the problem but is no permanent solution for me.

The nginx access log doesn't even list the first request so i am kind of clueless where to start debugging.

[Firefox Network Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drJMb.png) 
[Wireshark Screenshot of first ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEjW4.png)

Firefox: 46.0.1
Nginx: 1.10
JQuery: 2.22

Comment: There are some strange issues with HTTP/2 and CORS in Firefox (but I don't see the preflight request in your headers, which baffles me a  bit). My advice is thus that you do everything at your reach to be sure that CORS is not biting you.

Comment: Which Cipher Suites you use? I recommend you to use configuration suggested by [Mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=nginx-1.1.10&openssl=1.0.2h&hsts=yes&profile=intermediate) for intermediate or modern. You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with CORS because the ajax call targets the same domain. I tried different Cipher Suites including Mozilla's one without success.

Comment: Also added a wireshark screenshot of the first ajax call, sadly i really can't  spot something there...

Comment: @r3vile I have almost the same problem with FF.
but for me it is a first request after a long inactivity after page reload.
and that request does not register in nginx access log.
has nothing to do with CORS as none of us uses it. 
and its neither SPDY nor HTTP2 problem as I had them enabled long before nginx 1.10 and they worked ok. 
unfortunately I don't have nginx config file from before the update to find what was changed 
so right now I'm kind of stuck and experimenting with settings.

Answer (score 0):

it is a Firefox bug that affects only version 46.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269055.

downgrading nginx to 1.9.7 (some people say even up to 1.9.11) also helps

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with IExplorer 10 and 11 - same issue: the culprit is nginx v1.10. Post request does not complete after a period of idle.

Update nginx to at least v1.11 in order to fix the problem.